# JavaScript template engine which uses cloneNode

Tags: javascript, templates, clonenode

Is there a JS template engine which doesn't work with strings, but rather with document fragments?

The problem with strings is that they need to be converted into DOM objects, which is a slow and costly operation, especially if you need to make a lot of separate fragments.

I rolled my own simple engine and tested it against Underscore's engine. However my engine is pretty basic - it doesn't  support any logic except each iterators. The tests have shown that it works faster... you can try it yourself:

http://jsperf.com/ngit-templating/8

I'm wondering is there a complete solution which works this way?

Comment: I question your premise that turning strings into DOM objects is slow. Browsers are **extremely** good at doing that. Try benchmarking against template functions produced by [doT.js](https://github.com/olado/doT).

Comment: That link is throwing an error: `ReferenceError: engine3 is not defined.`

Comment: There are projects that use [JSON ML](http://jsonml.org) as their basis. Perhaps check out some of the linked projects to see if they fit your needs.